# Check for files in 3 separate folders and rename if exist with filename(1), filename(2)

Tags: python

Task 1: I've completed.

Write a python script to generate three sets of 50 files (150 files total) with random dates in the file name from within the last 50 days:

IT421_unixdate.txt, IT151_unixdate.txt, IT620_unixdate.txt

Task 2:

Write a python script to:

1. Check if the folders IT421, IT151, IT620 exist, if they do not, create them. Move the files that begin with ITx to the folder ITx
2. If the file already exists in the folder, rename it like the following  example:

`IT421_1456991403.txt` becomes `IT421_1456991403(1).txt`, `IT421_1456991403(1).txt` becomes `IT421_1456991403(2).txt`, and so on….

I am stuck on task2 part 2

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import random
import time
import os

folders = ["IT421", "IT151", "IT620"]

#task2(1)

for i in range(0,len(folders)):

    if not os.path.exists(folders[i]):
        os.mkdir(folders[i])

#task1
    for i in range (0,50):
        for classIT in folders:
            pastFiftyDays = int(time.time()) - 432000
            currentTime = int(time.time())
            timeStamp = str(random.randrange(pastFiftyDays, currentTime))

            #Task2(2)   
            if classIT == "IT151":
                open('IT151/' + classIT + "_" + timeStamp + .txt".format(classIT), "w")
            elif classIT == "IT421":
                open('IT421/' + classIT + "_" + timeStamp + ".txt".format(classIT), "w")
            else:
                open('IT620/' + classIT + "_" + timeStamp + ".txt".format(classIT), "w")
```

This is somewhere along the lines of what I've been trying.

```
    #!/usr/local/bin/python3
    import os
    import fnmatch

    folders = ["file_a", "file_z", "file_c"]
    for i in range(0,len(folders)):
        x = folders[i]
        for filename in os.listdir('./temp'):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, folders[i] + '.txt'):
                    open('temp/' + x + "(1).txt".format(x), "w")
            else:
                    open('temp/' + x + ".txt".format(x), "w")
```

I am new to python and have been working and searching for days for ways to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please clarify what the problem is? "I'm stuck" is not very helpful. You're stuck doing what? Does the code run? Does it give the wrong output? Do you get any errors? Please take a moment to read through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you're missing a quote in `timeStamp + .txt"` before the `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first portion of code works. It put the timestamp with random Unix dates on the end of the the three items in the folders list and I add the string ".txt" to the end as it writes each file to the appropriate folder based on the file matching the folder heading. That other block of code is what I've been struggling with. I have been testing that code separately to see if I could get it to work before adding it to my other code.

Comment: The problem is that when I run the code it will only place the files in the else statement if there is already an existing file in the folder. I also need it to work on all three folders 'IT151' 'IT620" and 'IT421' at the same time. Then it has to check if there is already a file with the same name in the folder and append the new file with a (1) or (2)...depending on the number of files with that name in the folder. Again the bottom is just code I've been testing before I implement it with the rest of my program. I  am stuck and am not sure how to procede. Thanks